# Visual FoxPro OLE DB Performance issues looping on DBF file

Tags: c#, .net, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have a .DBF file (Well, 6 DBF files with the same structure) that have over a million and a half rows. I also have a C# app that is migrating this data into a SQL database using an API we made.

The program starts quickly, being able to process 30 or 40 rows a second, but it gradually slows down over time, and I don't know why. I believe I am disposing of objects at a good pace.

The connection string I am using in the vfpoledb is

```
"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=" + sourceDBFolder + ";Collating Sequence=machine;MVCOUNT=32000;ENGINEBEHAVIOR=90;TABLEVALIDATE=0;REFRESH=0";
```

Where sourceDBFolder is a path on disk. I also execute the following code before starting the task:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand oRefreshCommand = oConn.CreateCommand();
oRefreshCommand.CommandText = "EXECSCRIPT([SET REFRESH TO 0,0])";
oRefreshCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here is the relevant code. The where clauses in the select statement will cause a bottleneck if they are not put in the order below.

```
string[] noteTables = new string[] { "note1", "note2", "note3", "note4", "note5", "note6" };
foreach (long lNoteKey in oCaseLookupTable.Keys) {
  for (int y = 0; y <= 5; y++) {
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand oNotesCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
    oNotesCmd.CommandText = "SELECT NOTEDATE, NOTEDESC, ENTEREDBY FROM " + noteTables[y] + " WHERE NOTEPOINT = " + lNoteKey.ToString() + " AND NOTEDESC NOT LIKE 'Folder accessed%'";
    DataTable oNotesTable = new DataTable();
    oNotesTable.Load(oNotesCmd.ExecuteReader());
    foreach (DataRow oRow in oNotesTable.Rows) { 
      //Do processing on rows, Note is my created class.
      Note oNote = new Note();
      oNote.NoteValue = oRow["NOTEDESC"].ToString().Trim();
      oNote.ReferenceID = oCaseLookupTable[lNoteKey];
      DateTime createdDate;
      if (DateTime.TryParse(oRow["NOTEDATE"].ToString().Trim(), out createdDate))
        oNote.CreatedDate = createdDate;
      else
        oNote.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
      Result oNoteResult = oNote.Insert();
    }
    oNotesTable.Dispose();
    oNotesCmd.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Simply put, I don't understand why this is gets gradually slower and slower. PerfMon doesn't show any blocks of managed memory growing over time. I try to keep my DataTable small by making continuous calls to the DBF file. In general, the largest number of rows that will be returned from query is 1,000.

Comment: why don't you do this with one select, eg.: WHERE (NOTEPOINT = 'note1' or NOTEPOINT = 'note2'....) AND NOTEDESC NOT LIKE ...

Comment: Well, there's about 6300 values in the oCaseLookupTable.Keys collection. I suppose I could just use one select for each of the tables, grabbing all rows in that table, and skip the row if I can't find a match on my Keys collection, but I was doing that before and it was just as slow.

Comment: What is the ONote.Insert doing?  Seems like there may be something going on in the Insert that is causing the slow down.  Is there some query running that takes longer and longer the more records get put into the SQL table?

Comment: oNote.Insert creates a new SqlConnection and SqlCommand, and performs SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar. The command itself is composed of two parts: A basic insert statement with about 10 columns, and then a call to SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the ID value of the Note we just entered (which isn't actually needed in this case, so if that is a big cause of slowdown, it can be removed)

Comment: I don't see anywhere that SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY causes a big performance hit over time, but say you were inserting 500,000 rows, and calling it each time. Would it make each subsequent call go slower and slower?

Comment: SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY should not impact performance.  You might consider commenting out the code that does the INSERT to see if the slowdown still occurs.  If it does not then that is a pretty good clue that the slowdown has something to do with the INSERT logic.

Comment: Issue RESOLVED. It was some database triggers on the SQL side. Disabling them fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was some database triggers on tables on the SQL side. Disabling them for the duration of the operation (They're not needed in this case) solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is the query you are executing Rushmore optimised, i.e. are there indexes on the tables for fields NOTEPOINT and NOTEDESC?

Comment: NOTEDESC is a memo field, and does not have an index. NOTEPOINT does have an index, but the Expression field for the index (I am looking at it with DBF Manager) is STR(NOTEPOINT) + RIGHT(NOTEDATE, 4) + LEFT(NOTEDATE, 2) + SUBSTR (NOTEDATE, 4, 2)

Comment: In that case to be even partially optimised your SELECT statement has to match that index expression. So I'm wondering if it's just getting bogged down because of that. Conversely, is it possible to add another index to the VFP table to match your query ?

Comment: You could also make it fully rushmore optimized just including the entire key expression in the WHERE clause, although I don't believe that is where the slowdown is occurring its worth a try...

"SELECT NOTEDATE, NOTEDESC, ENTEREDBY FROM " + noteTables[y] + " WHERE STR(NOTEPOINT) + RIGHT(NOTEDATE, 4) + LEFT(NOTEDATE, 2) + SUBSTR (NOTEDATE, 4, 2) = " + lNoteKey.ToString() + " AND NOTEDESC NOT LIKE 'Folder accessed%'";

Comment: Would it be better to modify the index of the NOTEPOINT field so that it doesn't have anything to do with the NOTEDATE field? For example, just make the index of NOTEPOINT, just, NOTEPOINT? I am working on a copy of the data, so I can make modifications if I need to.

Comment: Adding another index is acceptable but not necessarily a better approach.  Keep in mind that every index adds a bit of overhead when inserting records.  Using the "STR(NOTEPOINT) + RIGHT(NOTEDATE, 4) + LEFT(NOTEDATE, 2) + SUBSTR (NOTEDATE, 4, 2)" index does not impact performance of the query.  The calculations do not take place during the query, it only tells VFP to use the existing index when filtering the data.

Comment: Just to clarify what I said above.  The index does not "negatively" impact the performance because of the expressions.  Specifying the expression exactly as stated with have a positive impact on performance because VFP will be able to Rushmore optimize the query when this expression is used.

Comment: Well, seeing as how I won't be doing inserts on the VFP data, it shouldn't be a problem. I'm thinking that I should have exported all of this data to a flat text file before I did this.

Comment: You'd be into a whole other realm of potential edge cases with a text file - stripping unwanted delimiters in the data, what about memo fields contents, and so on. Plus the text file has no index to help it, whereas DBF files do, when they're used properly.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the code to use the `DataReader` instead of a `DataTable`. Use a `while` loop to iterate the results.  I believe the `foreach` loop on the `DataTable` is also slowing things down. Since you are doing forward only reading of values, this will give you a performance improvement:

See [Performance Comparison: Data Access Techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978388.aspx) for more, especially the section `DataReader vs. DataSet`

> The DataReader is a better choice for applications that require
>   optimized read-only and forward-only data access. The sooner you load
>   the data off the DataReader, close the DataReader, and close the
>   database connection, the better performance you get. Because the
>   DataReader holds a database connection that cannot be used for any
>   other purpose while the application reads data, it could limit
>   scalability if the application holds the DataReader long enough for
>   contention to occur. The DataSet only needs to hold a connection while
>   it is being populated. Once it is filled, the connection may be closed
>   and returned to the pool. Delaying reading the data from the DataSet
>   will not cause contention to occur, as the connection might have been
>   returned to the pool already.

Comment: I changed the code such that the oNotesCmd.ExecuteReader creates an object I explicitly instantiate. Then I simply do a while(Reader.Reader()) and use the same columns, instead of the foreach. I actually get worse performance. I guess I don't understand what you mean by putting the result of the DataReader into a DataSet. In the code I have now, doesn't that use the DataReader object to fill a DataTable? At which point, the DataTable is totally in memory, and I am not accessing the database.

Comment: Would it be better, rather than using the first foreach loop on my list of longs, access the entire note table at once? And call a DataReader on that? There's also part of me that thinks that the index on the NOTEPOINT is unusual and could be part of the problem.